# Using a specific IterativeImputer in sklearn Pipeline for each column

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, imputation

I am running a regression algorithm and using sklearn Pipelines for preprocessing. Initially, I have used Iterative Imputer for all of my numeric columns, but I would rather prefer to add some additional steps for certain columns, and therefore use different preprocessing steps for each, or at least some columns. In some columns, zero value is valid, in others that is how missing values are marked.

```
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesRegressor, RandomForestRegressor
import sklearn.preprocessing
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_ml.iloc[:, :].drop(columns=['ClosePrice']), 
                                                    df_ml.iloc[:, :]['ClosePrice'], 
                                                    test_size=.33
                                                    )


tic = time.perf_counter()

cat_pipe = Pipeline([
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent'))
                     
                    ])

# Define numerical pipeline
# IterativeImputer(estimator=ExtraTreesRegressor())
num_pipe = Pipeline([
    ('imputer', IterativeImputer(estimator=ExtraTreesRegressor(), missing_values=-1))

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('cat', cat_pipe, categorical),
                                               ('num', num_pipe, numerical)

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor)])

#pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)

X_train_pre = pipe.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_pre = pipe.fit_transform(X_test)
print(X_train_pre.shape, X_test_pre.shape)
```

Numerical here represents a single column where -1 is a missing value indicator. When I run this code, all the missing values turn into the same value - 6.77.

```
pd.DataFrame(X_train_pre).iloc[:, -1].value_counts().head()

6.000000     899
7.000000     823
8.000000     673
5.000000     671
6.772953     511
```

I can see that is because the imputer is only taking considering one column that is labeled as numeric and taking the average. How do I make it so that it would consider all the columns in the dataset, especially the target variable?

Update: when I include several columns, the results are no longer the same, but I am still not able to specify which columns I would like to be added for consideration for the imputer when using a specific pipeline for each.

Answer (score 0):

The imputer takes into consideration only the columns that were passed to it. If you want to for example include some categorical columns to the imputation process of the numerical ones you need to pass the categorical columns to the pipeline as well.

```
numerical.extend(['cat1', 'cat2'])
```

The issue that arises here is you will have duplicates of the columns that were in both categorical and numerical pipelines, so you would have to do something about that, but I'm not really sure what exactly.

Taking the target variable into account during imputations seems like data leakage, so I do not recommend that.